# Ajax getting 400 Bad Request when submitting Form only on Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have written a php code in wordpress to submit a form using ajax. It working fine on chrome but getting 400 Bad request on Firefox. This is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery( 'form[name="contact-me"]' ).on( 'submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form_data = {};
         $(this).serializeArray().forEach( function(element){
            form_data[element.name] = element.value;
        });
        $.post(zt_send_form_obj.ajax_url, {
            action:      "zt_save_campain_form_data",
            _ajax_nonce:   zt_send_form_obj.nonce,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            values: JSON.stringify(form_data),
        }, function(data) {
            if (data.success) {
                if(data.data.info.message=='no'){
                    $('#myModal').show();
                    console.log('cod is in')
                }
                if(data.data.info.message=='yes'){
                    $('#CodeModal').show();
                    $('.the_cod_div').append('<span>'+data.data.info.code+'</span>');
                    console.log('data saved');
                }
                
            }
            else{
                console.log("not working");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What does the actual response look like? Do your server-side logs give you any hints?

Comment: You appear to be using [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) incorrectly. For example, `type` and `contentType` do not belong in the `data` object. Did you mean to use `$.ajax()` instead? If so, the property for data is `data`, not `values`

Comment: Response return 0.  server-side logs don't give me any hints

Comment: What about the Wordpress state? Are you signed in to wp-admin on just one of your chrome or firefox browsers? Have you set-up two wp actions? One for the `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}` and one for `wp_ajax_{$action}`?

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. By adding  ** wp_ajax_nopriv_{$action}**  error 400 was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('form[name="contact-me"]').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var form = $('#form_id')[0]; //set form id

        var varform = new FormData(form);

        varform.append("action", "zt_save_campain_form_data");

        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: varform,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (response) {

              //if success do this...
             console.log(response);

            },

            error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
                console.log(xhr, textStatus, error);
            }

        })

    });
```

Inside your form you can put this code for nonce validation

```
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'name_of_my_action', 'name_of_nonce_field' ); ?>
```